# How to write waitForElementText method in Playwright

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-typescript

I would like to have `waitForElementText()` in playwright.

E.g I have headers on each page `cssSelector = '.header-name'`.

and I navigate from Home page to Users

I pass two arguments to the method: `waitForElementText( locator: string, expectedText: string)`

and I want to wait for the header name to change from Home → Users

I tried to use `page.waitForFunction()` method but I get error:

```
page.waitForFunction: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'locator')
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your code and the page you're automating. I don't see why a normal locator for that text won't work though: `page.getByText("Users")`, optionally filtering on CSS selector if you need to disambiguate further.

Comment: You can't use `page` inside `waitForFunction` because `page` isn't defined in the browser console. It's a Node Playwright thing.

Comment: @ggorlen Yes, Thank you! I tried page.getByText("Users") and it works ok.

now my method look like here:


`async waitForElementText(elementLocator: string, expectedText: string)`

`{`

        `const generalLocator = this.page.locator(elementLocator);`

        `const pageNameLocator = pageNameLocator.getByText(expectedText);`

        `await pageNameLocator .waitFor({state: 'visible'});`

`}`

Answer (score 1):

Since Playwright's locator's API waits for elements automatically and has a text-based selector, `waitForText` is already in the API as `getByText`:

```js
await page.getByText("Users"); // for a substring match

// or an "exact" match (after whitespace normalization):
await page.getByText("Users", {exact: true});

// or as an assertion:
await expect(page.getByText("Users", {exact: true})).toBeVisible();
```

You can chain locators if this isn't enough to disambiguate the element:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.39.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<h1 class="header-name">  Users  </h1></body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.firefox.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page
   .locator(".header-name")
   .getByText("Users", {exact: true})
   .waitFor();
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use auto- retrying assertion [toHaveText](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-text)

It **waits until** the Locator points to an element with the given text. You can use regular expressions for the value as well.

```
const locator = page.locator('.title');
await expect(locator).toHaveText(/Welcome, Test User/);
await expect(locator).toHaveText(/Welcome, .*/);
```